# Refer same Crystal Report (.rpt) multiple times in same solution

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an app developed in `C#`. Through the solution, i have several places (projects) where i want to call a specific report that is in a different project. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Anyone has any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: For those struggling with the same problema, i created a thread in Visual Studio Forum and got some answers: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df094a9d-9e16-445b-bad6-b62e77a1a3ce/refer-to-a-crystal-report-in-a-different-project?forum=csharpgeneral                                                                                                                                                                                                       Hope this helps.